# How to set up celery producer send task timeout

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have tried **broker_connection_timeout** settings and seems it's not what I expected. The documentation [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-broker_connection_timeout),  said the following:

> "The broker connection timeout only applies to a worker attempting to
>   connect to the broker. It does not apply to producer sending a task,
>   see **broker_transport_options** for how to provide a timeout for that
>   situation."

But until now I still cannot find the correct **broker_transport_options** for `RabbitMQ` to set timeout for `send_task`. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this config

BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {"max_retries": 3, "interval_start": 0, "interval_step": 0.2, "interval_max": 0.5}

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4627#issuecomment-396907957

Answer (score 0):

It should work... The only case when it does not work (and that is by design) is if you are using gevent. - That is a documented behaviour.

Say you use a file `celeryconfig.py` to configure Celery (by using `config_from_object(yourpackage.celeryconfig)`)

It should have something like:

```
broker_transport_options = {"fanout_prefix": True,
                            "fanout_patterns": True,
                            "visibility_timeout": 86400,
                            "broker_connection_timeout", 10.0}
```